# gathering multiple promise results? (plain javascript)

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

I'm new to Promises and trying to load lots of results from localstorage first and if that fails, fall back on getting the data from a server. I don't want to use jquery - ignore that I'm currently using $.getJSON :-/

```
function loader1() {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        localforage.getItem("data1").then(function (value) {
            if (value !== null) {
                resolve(value);
            } else {
                $.getJSON("/myapp/data1.json").then(function (data) {
                    if (data !== null) {
                        resolve(data);
                    }
                }).catch(function (err) {
                    reject(err);
                });
            }
        });
    });
}
```

which is fine for one file. So then I'd

```
loader1().then(function(result) { 
    // we have a result
    doSomethingElse();
}).catch(function (err) {
    // problem
});
```

But I want to do this for multiple files, some of which are in localstorage and some of which load json from a remote source. I want to load everything, and when it's finished, perform the next step of my app.

`Promise.all` appears to be the thing, but I can't see how to get the results of each of the loaders; I was thinking it would be like:

```
Promise
    .all([loader1, loader2, loader3])
    .then(function(result1,result2,result3)) {
        ...
```

but this isn't how it works ... so I tried

```
Promise
    .all([loader1, loader2, loader3])
    .then(function(result)) {
        // var result1 = result[0];
        // var result2 = result[1];
        // var result3 = result[1];
```

but the results of the second are the functions not the returned values ...

Searching many sites indicated that promise systems like Q and bluebird have a `spread` method which looks like what I want. can I do this in plain old javascript (how?) or should I look at using a library like Q or RSVP instead?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best es6 way to get name based results with Promise.all](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35297446/best-es6-way-to-get-name-based-results-with-promise-all)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> but the results of the second are the functions not the returned
> values ...

You are not resolving any value form the `Promise` you construct. You are also not returning any values form the succeeding `.then`'s in the chain.
You need to do the following for each of your loader functions:

```
function loader1() {

    var data = localforage.getItem("data1");
    
    data.then(function (data) {

        if (data !== null) {
             return data;
        } else {
            data = $.getJSON("/myapp/data1.json")

            if (data !== null) {
                return data;
            } else {
                return Error;
        }

    data.catch(function (err) {
       return (err);
    }
```

This ensures that a call to function loader1() will either return a resolved `Promise` or a rejected `Promise`. You can then use the solution suggested by guest271314:

```
Promise
.all([loader1(), loader2(), loader3()])
.then(function(result) {
  // var result1 = result[0];
  // var result2 = result[1];
  // var result3 = result[1];
 })
 .catch(function (err) {
   // problem
 });
```

However please be aware that a `Promise` executes *synchronously*. This means that it does not automatically wait on any asynchronous action to complete inside the `Promise`. You have to take care of this yourself by only resolving it once the asynchronous action has completed (typically by resolving in a callback passed to an asynchronous function).

Comment: `localforage.getItem` itself returns on a promise. Isn't this saying to resolve when localforage is called (it may not yet have resolved). That is, if `localforage` fails then fallback on getting data via xhr/elsewhere, then if all that fails reject everything.

Comment: I have updated my answer in accordance with your information that `local forage.getItem` returns a `Promise`.

Comment: Also you should note that even though a `.then` automatically returns a `Promise` you still need to return something inside the callback function passed to it - otherwise the `.then` will return a `Promise` with the value `undefined`

Comment: Also note that the `Promise`returned from `localforage.getItem` will be a one that is already either `resolved` or `rejected` and therefore you should act upon it using `.then` as a `Promise` by design only can be `resolved` or `rejected` once.

Comment: This is brilliant :) Promise
.all() +1

Answer (score 5):

Call the functions

```
Promise
.all([loader1(), loader2(), loader3()])
.then(function(result) {
  // var result1 = result[0];
  // var result2 = result[1];
  // var result3 = result[1];
 })
 .catch(function (err) {
   // problem
 });
```

See also [How to cache a downloaded javascript fle which is downloaded using script tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39784514/how-to-cache-a-downloaded-javascript-fle-which-is-downloaded-using-script-tag/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [destructuring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35297446/best-es6-way-to-get-name-based-results-with-promise-all):

```
Promise.all([loader1(), loader2(), loader3()])
.then(function([result1, result2, result3]) {
  ...
```