# Promise run then() but don't return the right data

Tags: node.js, promise

#### Resolved with answers, thanks everyone

EDIT :
I want my `updateInventory` function to return an object that have a property for each promise.
I can not know neither which ones will be used nor the order
The problem is that `t.batch` and `Promise.all` return an index array so I can not associate a promise to its component to output an object like I want.

Inspired by this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35297446/best-es6-way-to-get-name-based-results-with-promise-all) I did this:

The `then` in `getStatement` is executed first to format the resulting data of each promise : an object with `name` and `data` properties.
Then `t.batch` is resolved with all of these objects. The result is still an index array but each object contains the name and the data.
So I can create my final object.
Maybe there is a better way to do it ?

An example below :
My input :

```js
{
    device: {
        deviceId: 1,
        name: "myName",
        istate: "updated"
    },
    system: {
        systemId: 50,
        domain: 'foo.fr',
        istate: "updated"
    },
    ifaces: [
        {
            interfaceId: 75,
            name: "Iface Update 1",
            istate: "updated"
        },
        {
            name: "New Interface 1",
            istate: "added"
        }
    ]
}
```

"standard" Output with only `t.batch()` or `Promise.all() : an index array

```js
[
    0: { deviceId: 1 },
    1: { systemId: 50 },
    2: [
        { interfaceId: 75 },
        { interfaceId: 76 }
    ]
]
```

My custom `t.batch` output :

```js
[
    0: { name: "device", data: { deviceId: 1 }}
    1: { name: "system", data: { systemId: 50 }}
    2: { name: "ifaces", data: [{ interfaceId: 75 },{ interfaceId: 76 }] }
]
```

And then I can build my final object (`values.forEach` below) :

```js
{
  "device": { deviceId: 1 },
  "system": { systemId: 50 },
  ifaces: [
        { interfaceId: 75 },
        { interfaceId: 76 }
  ]
}
```

The code (simplified):

```js
function updateInventory(params) {
  const { /* hidden */, ...components } = params.data; // simplified
  
  return Database.tx('Inventory-Update', t => { // postgres transaction with pg-promise library
    const statements = []; // promise array

    for(let [prop, component] of Object.entries(components)) {
      statements.push(getStatement(t, prop, component));
    }

    return t.batch(statements);
  }).then(results => {
    let result = {};
    results.forEach(res => {
      result[res.name] = res.data;
    });
    return result;
  });
}

function getStatement(t, prop, component) {
  const repo = getReposName(prop);
  const state = component.istate;

  let statement;

  switch(state) {
    case "updated":
      statement = t[repo].update(component);
      break;
    case "removed":
      statement = t[repo].delete(component);
      break;
    default:
      statement = t[repo].insert(component);
      break;
  }
  
  return statement.then(res => {
    return {name: prop, data: res };
  });
}
```

Comment: It's very difficult when you speak in terms of line numbers. Please provide an minimal example and whats not working.

Comment: @Vishnudev, that last comment does not make sense. calling `then` does not make code wait. Also, it does not influence the value of `statement`.

Comment: A few things look wrong with the code, starting with `t[repo]`, which causes loss of the calling context. Should pass in just `t`, and then do `t.repo` inside instead. And then this attempt at resolving the promises twice - one time inside the transaction function, when calling `t.batch`, and another time inside `getStatement`.

Comment: If `statement` is `Promise` in your `getStatement` (which seems to be the case) then the output (array of promises) is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is based on how Promises works. `then` means that after promise is resolved, it will run next part. However you can have multiple `then` added to single promise and they do not affect each other.

You can see in this example that the Promise all is resolved before the `then` statements (because it just wait for statement to be finished, not for the waitABit part).

```js
function getStatement() {
  const statement = waitABit();

  statement.then(res => {
    let foo={name: Math.random(), data: [Math.random()] };
    console.log(foo);
    return foo;
  });
  return statement;
}

async function waitABit() {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve,1000));
}

async function callAll() {
  statements = [];
  for (let i=0; i < 3; i++){
    statements.push(getStatement());
  }
  console.log(await Promise.all(statements));
}

callAll();
```

This part is easy to fix:

```js
    function getStatement() {
      let statement = waitABit();

      const afterStatement = statement.then(res => {
        let foo={name: Math.random(), data: [Math.random()] };
        console.log(foo);
        return foo;
      });
      return afterStatement;
    }

    async function waitABit() {
      return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve,1000));
    }

    async function callAll() {
      statements = [];
      for (let i=0; i < 3; i++){
        statements.push(getStatement());
      }
      console.log(await Promise.all(statements));
    }

    callAll();
```

But in your case its probably also not an option, because after that you will put your promises that will be resolved with `nam` and `data` into `t.batch(statements);` which will probably fail.

You need to approach this in different way - i.e. getStatement will return data structure with these updates in DB and with the data you need, then you wait till the data updates and then you continue further.

Comment: Note that he cannot use `Promise.all` in his context, because he needs to settle all promises, which is what `t.batch` does there.

Answer (score 1):

Your expectation is *wrong* and the output you get is correct (array of promises)

Simple example:

```js
function getPromise() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve("data"), 200)
  })
}

function something() {
  // codes ...
  let res = getPromise()
  res.then(d => {
    // you're expecting this to be returned, but remember this runs in Future
    // this part of execution happens after res is returned in the last line
    console.log('this is executed after return')
    return d;
  })
  return res; // <-- this is what is actually returned
}

console.log(something())
```

Note: for some reason I can see only `{}`, not `Promise { <state>: "pending" }` while running this snippet in Firefox, if that is the case open your browser to confirm output is `Promise`

**Solution?**

Perhaps?:

```
// get rid of statement.then...
return { name, data: statement };
```

Answer (score 1):

One problem is that `.then()` returns a new promise so you need to change this:

```
  statement.then(res => {
    let foo={name: name, data: res };
    console.log(foo);
    return foo;
  });
  return statement;
```

to this:

```
  return statement.then(res => {
    let foo={name: name, data: res };
    console.log(foo);
    return foo;
  });
```

You need to be returning the new promise that `.then()` returns because that's the promise that will have `foo` as the resolved value.